# Kinesis Client Library for Consumers - Managing Dynamo DB tables

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kcl

We have multiple consumers reading from the same stream. So everytime there is new consumer, a new table is created in DynamoDB. These consumers are not permanent. Once they are shutdown, the table becomes redundant.

1.If we keep the application name same across consumers, Data records not read properly.
2. If we use different Application Name for each consumer, the DynamoDB is flooded with tables.

Is there a solution to handle this case?

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tried this myself, but probably you can enter a CloudWatch alarm/trigger for "DELETE DYNAMODB TABLE IF IDLE FOR 24H" or something like that.

It is a known practice for EC2 Instances, so maybe applies to DynamoDB as well. See: [Use Amazon CloudWatch to Detect and Shut Down Unused Amazon EC2 Instances](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/01/08/use-amazon-cloudwatch-to-detect-and-shut-down-unused-amazon-ec2-instances/)